# gVim very slow start with guioptions-=T

Tags: vimrc, gvim, startup

I'm experiencing the problem with gvim taking ~20 secs to start when I have  `guioptions-=T` in my .vimrc.

Tried both version 8.1.0875 and 8.2.0121

I found this bug report which is now closed, but the proposed solution didn't work for me: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5246

Anyone else has this problem and knows a solution?

Comment: Try running with an extra `--startuptime gvimstart.log` to find where the startup time is being spent exactly.

Comment: I know where the time is spent: in the GUI startup due to that option

Comment: Attaching that log to the issue in Vim would be useful! I'd recommend you reopen that issue upstream. Also, make sure you list the whole set of settings in your build including the `--version` output.